# CSS items alignment

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox, media-queries

This is my goal here with the buttons when I have a width of 800px or more:

[image]

And this is what I want to have when I have a a screen width of 400px to 799px:
[image]

But my problem now is I keep having this on both screen sizes:
[image]

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="top">
                <button class="red" onclick="changeColor('red')">r</button>
                <button class="yellow" onclick="changeColor('yellow')">y</button>
                <button class="blue" onclick="changeColor('rgb(0, 119, 255)')">b</button>
                <button class="green" onclick="changeColor('green')">g</button>
                <button class="purple" onclick="changeColor('purple')">p</button>
                <button class="orange" onclick="changeColor('orange')">o</button>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <button class="bluegreen" onclick="changeColor('rgb(32, 123, 131)')">bg</button>
                <button class="blueviolet" onclick="changeColor('blueviolet')">bv</button>
                <button class="yellowgreen" onclick="changeColor('yellowgreen')">yg</button>
                <button class="redviolet" onclick="changeColor('#c71585')">rv</button>
                <button class="redorange" onclick="changeColor('rgb(255, 102, 0)')">ro</button>
                <button class="yelloworange" onclick="changeColor('#ffae42')">yo</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
}

.block {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

Note: I removed those divs with the classes `.top` and `.bottom` on my HTML which makes it possible for me to have my buttons aligned as what the first two images above show. But then I return those divs to have the result on the third image.

Comment: Move these properties `display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;` to the `.block`

Comment: Thanks @ZohirSalak.

Answer (score 0):

Change css of block class like this:

```
.block {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `flex` element should be the `.block` DIV, with changing `flex-direction` to `column` in a media query:

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fca;
  border:none;
}

@media (max-width: 799px) {
  .block {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="top">
      <button class="red" onclick="changeColor('red')">r</button>
      <button class="yellow" onclick="changeColor('yellow')">y</button>
      <button class="blue" onclick="changeColor('rgb(0, 119, 255)')">b</button>
      <button class="green" onclick="changeColor('green')">g</button>
      <button class="purple" onclick="changeColor('purple')">p</button>
      <button class="orange" onclick="changeColor('orange')">o</button>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <button class="bluegreen" onclick="changeColor('rgb(32, 123, 131)')">bg</button>
      <button class="blueviolet" onclick="changeColor('blueviolet')">bv</button>
      <button class="yellowgreen" onclick="changeColor('yellowgreen')">yg</button>
      <button class="redviolet" onclick="changeColor('#c71585')">rv</button>
      <button class="redorange" onclick="changeColor('rgb(255, 102, 0)')">ro</button>
      <button class="yelloworange" onclick="changeColor('#ffae42')">yo</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the `flex-basis` for your buttons to align as you specified:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
}

/* Fit all 12 buttons on 1 row on large desktop */
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  button {
    flex-basis: 8%;
  }
}

/* Fit 12 buttons on 2 rows with 6 buttons per row, on smaller desktop */
@media (max-width: 400px) and (max-width: 799px) {
  button {
    flex-basis: 16%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <button class="red" onclick="changeColor('red')">r</button>
    <button class="yellow" onclick="changeColor('yellow')">y</button>
    <button class="blue" onclick="changeColor('rgb(0, 119, 255)')">b</button>
    <button class="green" onclick="changeColor('green')">g</button>
    <button class="purple" onclick="changeColor('purple')">p</button>
    <button class="orange" onclick="changeColor('orange')">o</button>
    <button class="bluegreen" onclick="changeColor('rgb(32, 123, 131)')">bg</button>
    <button class="blueviolet" onclick="changeColor('blueviolet')">bv</button>
    <button class="yellowgreen" onclick="changeColor('yellowgreen')">yg</button>
    <button class="redviolet" onclick="changeColor('#c71585')">rv</button>
    <button class="redorange" onclick="changeColor('rgb(255, 102, 0)')">ro</button>
    <button class="yelloworange" onclick="changeColor('#ffae42')">yo</button>
  </div>
</div>
```